# HttpResponseRedirect reverse - passing context variable

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a 'HttpResponseRedirect reverse' setup on a view which is calculating a poll result. I have passed an args to identify the poll via the poll id.

```
HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('poll:polling', args=(p.id,)))
```

I would like to pass the winner id to the polling view but don't know how to do so. Passing it via the url is not possible since results can be manipulated.Thanks

Comment: @Brandon so far after trying a few solutions I have come to realize passing it on the URL args is risky. Additionally, I can use kwargs but that is again a part of the URL (not sure about this). I have been looking for content for some time now and haven't been to find relevance. I would also like to add that I am a beginner so there is a possibility I may have missed something simple.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend having your views modify data based on the presence of parameters, which is what it sounds like is happening from your question. Daniel's solution will work just fine for what you need to do.

Comment: @Brandon thanks Brandon. I have reviewed the content given below by Daniel however, given the nature of my experience I am struggling a bit to implement it in my particular scenario.

Comment: Daniel's edit has all the information you need. Don't forget to enable sessions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/#enabling-sessions

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass data between views but don't want to put it in the URL, then you should use the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/).

**Edit**

This has nothing to do with authentication. It's as simple as putting a value into the session in one view, and getting it out in the other. So:

```
request.session['winner_id'] = my_winner_id
```

and

```
winner_id = request.session['winner_id']
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I am new to sessions (new to development), I have gone through the content and browsed over some articles which give more info on this subject. However, I am still not sure how to use it in my example. I do not have user authentication implemented. Can you provide some help on that.